# Compilation error when running perl code to access xlsx sheet

Tags: excel, perl, exception

I have the below code:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use Text::Iconv; 
use Spreadsheet::XLSX; 
use Date::Format;

my $converter = Text::Iconv -> new ("utf-8", "windows-1251"); 

# Read the data from a file.
my $prod_otp = Spreadsheet::XLSX->new('/home/shahk/Book1.xlsx', $converter);   
if (!defined $prod_otp ) { 
   die $prod_otp->error(), ".\n" ; 
}
```

But, when I try to run, I get the below error:

```
Argument "#REF!" isn't numeric in int at /tools/oss/packages/Spreadsheet/XLSX/Fmt2007.pm line 94.
```

Can someone please help me out in overcoming this kind of error?

Thanks!

Comment: The error comes from inside a `.pm` file from the `Spreadsheet::XLSX` module, and it is expecting a number, but getting a string. This happens on line 94 of the file. Look for something like `int($var)` where `$var` is incorrectly set to a string `#REF!`. It is not a fatal error, though it is probably a sign something is not working properly.

Comment: @user3035061 try without converter , see if still fails.

Comment: @michael501 Same error.

Comment: @user3035061 , did you remove '$convertor' from XLSX->new ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, `#REF!` is some sort of error message from Excel that comes from using a broken reference to a cell. When I look at the source code, it is expecting a numeric field (`if ($oCell->{Type} eq 'Numeric')`) and doing a rather silly comparison `if (int($number) != $number)`, presumably to check whether `$number` is a float, in which case it sets a format variable to `0.00`, else `0`. So the answer is that the spreadsheet parser is not correctly parsing a file with broken references. Perhaps you should try another parser.

Comment: @TLP: I think it is expecting numeric value instead it is being fed string as you said. What will you suggest next? Do I have to change anything in excel sheet like hack first row and column or something? Sorry, I am not sure how to proceed and I am stuck in here.

Comment: If you read CPAN bug reports and reviews, you will see that this (and other similar errors) are a known issue.  See [here](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/Spreadsheet-XLSX) and [here](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=86663).  The first link describes the cause as follows _"Two quibbles: if the XLSX file contains any #REF cell errors, this is echoed to STDERR with no option I can find to ignore these (or to track where they came from)."_  The second link includes a patch which probably could be used or adapted to resolve this issue, since the problem is similar.

Comment: @user3035061 Well, the obvious answer is to load the file in an excel reader and fix the reference errors. Or try a different parser and see if that helps.

Comment: @TLP: Another parser huh.. can you suggest which one to use?

Comment: @David: I cannot open the links. Does it require login?

Comment: @user3035061 Your guess is as good as mine. I'm sure its been asked before, so look around. If I were you, I would first look at the data in Excel, though. Or if you don't have excel, OpenOffice, or Google docs.

Comment: Hmmmm... no, they're just standard links.  Nothing special and no login required.  I just checked them again and they seem fine.  Here are the raw links:  (1) http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/Spreadsheet-XLSX (2) https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=86663

Comment: @TLP : Ok let me dig some more. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3035061 You're welcome. You could add some tags to your question for the excel format and see if that brings some people here with more expertise about excel.

Comment: @TLP: ok let me try that.

Comment: @michael501: Sorry, I missed your question. Yes, I removed converter from xlsx->new().

Comment: Adding parser Spreadsheet::XLSX::Fmt2007 worked. I decided to add this parser as the error it was showing was in the routine sub FmtString { } . atleast, now when I run the script I dont see this error.

Comment: @user3035061 Please make that into an answer so future visitors can see what the solution was.

Answer (score 1):

Adding parser Spreadsheet::XLSX::Fmt2007 worked. I decided to add this parser as the error it was showing was in the routine sub FmtString { } . atleast, now when I run the script I dont see this error

Comment: What do you mean when you say you added a parser?